# How we get the access of Obect class method's? even we are NOT extending (Obects class) into our child class?

Tags: java

we don't write like this -

class Object{}

class Myclass extends Object{

// Still we can access the methods of the Object class.

}

Comment: What do you mean by accessing Object's method ? First of all, you don't need to extend Object explicitly. Object is the root parent of every object in java. And you certainly can override its methods and call them in your sub-class, when allowed: toString() and wait() for example.

Comment: How the "Object is the root parent of every object in java?" ????

Comment: Does that uses extends keyword??

Answer (score 0):

Java does that for you. All classes in Java inherit from Object. This is how it is implemented in Java.

Java compiler is made to understand your classes extend Object implicitly just like how you don't have to import Java.lang package

Comment: Hey Avinash, 
I'm aware about this! 
please explain "What Java (Compiler) does implicitly ?" for both "Object class" and for "import Java.lang package" ?

Comment: @JayJain Explain it how? There's nothing to explain. That's what the compiler does. That's how the language is defined.

Answer (score 0):

All Java objects are children of **Object** by default.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/overview-tree.html

Comment: @JayJain No. Your question was about inheritance from Object. If this is a new question, it should be in a new thread.

Comment: Java compiler knows the fact and acts accordingly as if such inheritances has been declared.  If you are interested how exactly this part of compiler is implemented, then it's the whole other question.

Answer (score 0):

> How we get the access of Obect class method's? even we are NOT extending (Obects class) into our child class?

Because you ARE, unless you have explicitly extended another class. 'extends Object' is the default.

Comment: Is the 'extends Object' written by the Java (Compiler) implicitly?

Comment: Hey EJP, Thanks a lot for you time, understanding and answering

Comment: Hey EJP, Thanks a lot for your time, understanding and answering my question's answer!

if "Java (Compiler) implicitly" writes "extends" keyword for Object class.. makes me easy to say Object is the parent class of all the classes in JAVA! Or we can then call methods of object class.